# Using Ruby, how can I iterate over a for loop n.times

Tags: ruby, for-loop

I have a basic ruby loop

```
for video in site.posts
  video.some_parameter
endfor
```

I want to run this loop 2 or 3 times.

Is this possible?

Comment: I am sorry to be asking such a simple question but I have reviewed the documentation, just still not sure how to run a for loop 3 times.

Answer (score 116, accepted):

```
3.times do
   # do work here
end
```

check http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_loops.htm

Comment: so just run a do loop around the for loop?

Comment: Yes, unless you want something different.  If you try it and play with the code you will answer all\most of your questions.  Just debug and print what the code is doing.

Comment: How do you retrieve the index if you need it?

Comment: @GrahamS. I know this is old but you just need to add `|i|` after `do` like so `3.times do |i|`

Answer (score 20):

If you need an index:

```
5.times do |i|
  print i, " "
end
```

Returns:

`0 1 2 3 4`

Reference: https://apidock.com/ruby/Integer/times

Answer (score 10):

It's bad style to use **for**.

```
3.times do
  site.posts.each do |video|
    video.some_parameter
  end
end
```

or if **video.some_parameter** is one line,

```
3.times do
  site.posts.each { |video| video.some_parameter }
end
```

see: https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#source-code-layout