# "n.times do" block just returns value of n

Tags: ruby

Judging by the answers to  [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13036371/using-ruby-how-can-i-iterate-over-a-for-loop-n-times), I expected

```
@n.times do
  "hello"
end
```

to return a number of "hello"s equal to the value of `@n`. However, no matter how I modify the code, my rails console just returns the value of `@n` and nothing more. What am I doing wrong?

For example, if I first set `@n = 10`, then the result of the code would just be `10`.

Comment: It's only "returning" the value of @n because the rails console (or irb) everything in ruby is a statement and @n.times {} returns @n. If you want to print do `puts` as the answer suggests, if you want to get the values in an array do `.map`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nope, I don't see how you inferred from those answers that `.times` block should return anything. What it does is it runs specified block specified number of times, nothing more. Return values of the block are discarded. Will do if you want to, say, print "hello" to standard output N times or do some other work.

```
n.times do
  puts 'hello'
end
```

If you expected N copies of "hello" string in an array, then there are other ways to achieve this. For example:

```
Array.new(n, 'hello')
n.times.map { 'hello' } 
# and many others
```

Comment: Is it possible to print an image instead, using erb?

Comment: define "print an image"

Answer (score 2):

You are not printing anything. Try:

```
@n.times do
  puts "hello"
end
```

Comment: Is it possible to print an image instead, using erb?

Comment: I have never done it myself but yes you can print image. RMagick is the gem to read the image. Here is a link that explains how you can do it http://radek.io/2015/06/29/catpix/